# Why is my Python Dash app not rendering in the browser?

Tags: python, browser, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm and running the below code.  When I right-click on the code and select "Run File in Python Console" it gives me the following in the console. When I select the http://...., it starts to load up in the browser, but it keeps loading. It doesn't render the Hello World.

I've used PyCharm quite a bit and never had this issue until now.  I've tried it with and without the port statement below.

```
C:\Apps\App11\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2023.3/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --host=127.0.0.1 --port=51327 
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['C:\\Apps\\App11'])
PyDev console: starting.
Python 3.11.7 (tags/v3.11.7:fa7a6f2, Dec  4 2023, 19:24:49) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
runfile('C:\\Apps\\App11\\app.py', wdir='C:\\Apps\\App11')
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8057/
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: on
```

```
from dash import Dash, html

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(children='Hello World')
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8057)
```

I ran the code shown above with and without the `port=8057` in Chrome and Edge.  nothing is working.  I've run other codes (dash apps), and it has rendered. But won't here.

Comment: I ran this code and it worked perfectly fine. what error are you seeing ?

Comment: The browser just keeps loading.  It won't render the Hello World in the browser.  The spinner in the browser keeps going.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code and it worked perfectly fine on my PC, (`Windows 11`, `python 3.12`, `vs code`).

Nevertheless, maybe you can try similar code, but without specifying the port (possibly this is blocked).

so this:

```py
# Import the necessary libraries
import dash
from dash import html

# Initialize the Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Define the layout of the app
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello, World!'),
])

# Run the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

which also works on my pc, runs on port 8050.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8050/
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I put this in the code and it worked.  Not sure why PyCharm required this as the solution b/c this was supposed to address Jupyter notebook functionality and not PyCharm.  However, it does work.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```